# Read JSON File Xamarin Forms Weird Errors

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin, mobile

I just started to code with Xamarin Forms and I'm coding an Android App with Xamarin Forms.

I'm trying to read a `json` file but when I try to read it, it says that it can't find the file.

I've tried to put the file in many different folders in the project.

I put the json file's build action to Embedded Ressource but that still doesn't work. I don't really know where to put the file and how to import it. I tried many thing with StreamReader and many others things like JSONCovert from newtonsoft json.

```
private void LoadJson()
{
    string dispo = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Resources), "dispo.json")); ;

    var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
    var day = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Day>(dispo);

    ls.Add(day.Lundi);
    ls.Add(day.Mardi);
    ls.Add(day.Mercredi);
    ls.Add(day.Jeudi);
    ls.Add(day.Vendredi);
}
```

And

```
public class Day
{
    public string Lundi { get; set; }
    public string Mardi { get; set; }
    public string Mercredi { get; set; }
    public string Jeudi { get; set; }
    public string Vendredi { get; set; }
}
```

The result I'm getting :

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/dispo.json"
```

Where should I put the file?

Comment: Have you sent the file to copy always?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are saying about copy always?

Comment: Do you see the file in the solution explorer?

Comment: Yes It is there.

Comment: Click on it and bring the properties up, change it to copyalways, I can’t remember which setting, but it shouldn’t be hard to find

Answer (score 2):

The embedded resource content type is not actually a "file" in your application, but rather the bytes are inside the assembly itself. See the [working with files docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/files#loading-files-embedded-as-resources) and [sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WorkingWithFiles/) for how to extract an embedded resource.

```cs
var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(LoadResourceText)).Assembly;
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(
   "YourNamespace.dispo.json");

string text = "";
using (var reader = new StreamReader (stream))
{
    text = reader.ReadToEnd ();
}
```

Refer to [this code snippet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/files#debugging-embedded-resources) which writes out all the embedded resources to the application output debug window, it will help you see if your file is embedded properly.

**Alternatively**

The Android project system doesn't really let you just put a "file" anywhere and load it when the application runs. Instead you have to add it in **/Resources/raw/dispo.json** and then find the path like this:

```cs
var filePath = 
    Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), 
    "dispo.json")
```